# express js - ejs with layout template

Tags: express, ejs

In my express app,
I've changed the view engine to ejs.

Does anyone know if it is still possible to take advantage of view templates?

Comment: You can have layouts using this pattern https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 10):

Actually after Express 3.X is not support layout.ejs, if you want to use the layout, following steps should be done by yourself:

1. add dependency "express-partials": "*" in you `package.json` file

```
     "dependencies": {
       "express": "3.1.0",
       "ejs": "*",
       "express-partials": "*"
     }
```

1. execute `npm install` to install the latest version of `express-partials`
2. require `express-partials` in your `app.js`
   `var partials = require('express-partials');`
3. add code `app.use(partials());` under the `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` in `app.js` file

after that, you can design you `layout.ejs` and add `<%- body%>` block in your `layout.ejs` file, and that's enough and working well.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with this module...

https://github.com/aseemk/express-blocks

layout.ejs

```
<html>
    <body>
        <% include nav %>
        <h1><%= title %></h1>
        <%- body %>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.ejs

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<form>...</form>
```

nav.ejs

```
<nav>
  <% if ( session.logged_in ) { %>
    <a href="/account">account</a>
    <a href="/logout">logout</a>
  <% } else { %>
    <a href="/signup">signup</a>
    <a href="/login">login</a>
  <% } %>
  <a href="/">home</a>
</nav>
```

I was using express-partials, but I found express-blocks to be better for ejs and express 3.x. using partials was a pain to have to pass data in everytime. With `<% include whatever %>` the data is already accessible.

In your routes file, you can render like this:

```
exports.login.get = function(req, res){
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  res.render('login', { title: 'Login to your account' });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Express.js leaves that up to the template engine if I remember correctly. So if ejs doesn't support layouts then you are out of luck.

Comment: It supposedly supports layouts according to express's documentation, but I have yet to get it working correctly either.

Comment: 3.x removed layouts. The guides on the website are 2.x.

Comment: You can use ejs-locals to define a layout.

Comment: @Pickels is this still true? the guide on the site is pretty awful overall.

Comment: @onmouse as far as I know it's still true. If you need an engine with layout support that's not jade I can recommend swig. It's a really solid template engine with all the features of jade but without the haml syntax.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ejs-blocks package `npm install ejs-blocks`
2. In your app.js file import the package `const engine = require('ejs-blocks');`
   and configure view engine

   ```
   //settings
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
   app.engine('ejs', engine);
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   ```
3. In express by default the name of the file is `layout.ejs` So create a file called `layout.ejs` in your views folder with the next content:

**views/layout.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <%- body %>
</body>
<%- blocks.js %>
</html>
```

`<%= title %>` value is obtained when the file is called from route

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index", { title: "Hello world!" });
});
```

5. Each of your views must import the `layout.ejs` file in the first line, for example

**views/index.ejs**

```
<% layout('layout') -%>
<h1>Article title</h1>
<p>Content</p>
  ...
<% block('js', `<script>
    ...
</script>`) -%>
```

You can use `block` for insert code from the view to the main layout.